# osmdroid tile loading in new versions is very slow

Tags: android, osmdroid

Currently I'm using osmdroid version 3.0.7 and my question is why in
the newer versions  the map tile loading
is very very slow while using earlier versions (3.0.1 and before) it is much faster?
By the way, I'm using the mapnik tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few accepted bugs in 3.0.7, such as the tile cache not updating properly/fast when zooming, which have supposedly been fixed in the root source tree, but haven't yet made it into a new release jar.

i rolled back to 3.0.5 to fix my problem, until such time as these fixes make their way into a new release jar.

Comment: ya that's exactly what i did.
I'm currently using an earlier version from the repository.
thanks.

Comment: any updates on this issue?  what is the best version to be using right now?  I have tried the latest (3.0.8) from the googlecode site and having same issue.

Comment: Sorry, can't say as i've looked recently, as I didn't need any of the newer features right now.

Comment: @Patrick i recently tried with the latest 3.0.10 version and the map is loading properly ,i was previously using the 3.0.7 where i was having problem while loading the map tiles it was taking more time.

Comment: @NetStarter good to hear its working better.  I have moved on to use the google Maps V2 sdk with OSM tiles.  Works well but does not have caching.